# How the manager can get the data (or any update done in the container ) from the worker nodes in a docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am creating a docker swarm with one manager , and 3 worker nodes and the service that is running is bash terminal .How the manager can get the output of commands which are run on bash(terminal) containers on worker nodes 
Ex: If i run run ls on terminal of worker node, how the manager can get the output of ls

Answer (score 0):

To get the logs of one service use docker-cloud service logs https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/deploy-app/8_view_logs/

What are you trying to accomplish?
If you want to be able to control the output of the workers from a centralized point there is tools like portainer, universal comtrol plane which have nice uis and let you access logs of containers on the workers.

If you actually need data to be pressnt in the manager use a shared storage (like a mounted nfs drive) or scp the data you want.

Just remember a worker node can have multiple containers with each having their own stdout.